# Future of NHL story, children's Bank of Nova Scotia magazine

Tags: story-identification

I'm not sure this is science fiction, but it (was) futuristic, and played "what if" very well.  I'm also not sure it's possible to find.

Back in the 1970s or early 1980s, the Bank of Nova Scotia had a magazine that went out to the children that had the special children's savings accounts.  The usual stuff - how to manage money for 13 year olds, meet other account holders, and the like - but sometimes had a story in it.

And one I've remembered for ever was about the future of the NHL playoffs (I believe from 1990-2000?) where the rules and technology changed every year.  Each chapter was the "newspaper report" of the final game of the Stanley Cup playoffs, and one was about 19 periods, where they eventually had only one person on the ice for each team, pushing the puck around with their tongues; one was against the new moon team, and eventually went to laser sticks and pucks (and a new "melting" penalty).  All beautifully illustrated in true "TRON 80's" glory.

I'd love to find it again, but have no idea how.

Comment: From your description, the story seems to be clearly SF.

Comment: Though the story is sci fi, your question is about finding where you can get the magazine from, which is not sci fi.